# Ingress for TCP ports, is it possible to route to different services using the same port number in a similar way NGINX routes for http ports?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm not sure if this is possible, I have looked around the web but couldn't find anything.

I running kubernetes and using NGINX ingress, I can do layer 7 routing, allowing me to use a single port for incoming requests, then based upon the request, route that request to different services.

My question is: Is there anything like that, that could do the same or a similar thing for TCP & UDP ports?

e.g: So I can route traffic arriving at, lets say, TCP 9071 then route that traffic to different services based on some sort of flag/or traffic content.

It would be good to know if this is not possible as well?

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to route based on a URL because that's layer 7 HTTP(S). However, you can do TCP/UDP load balancing which is supported by most open source proxies.

- [Nginx Ingress Controller TCP/UDP](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/)
- [Traefik Ingress TCP/UDP](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/#kind-ingressroutetcp)
- [HAproxy TCP](https://haproxy-ingress.github.io/docs/configuration/command-line/#tcp-services-configmap)

✌️

Comment: In my case the services do different things. I'm assuming TCP/UDP load balancing kind of just round robins between the services...